# Extending Chips from angular-material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i'm trying to create a layer on top of the `md-chips` called `chip-filter`

Which has some extra functionality build in;e.g.

- a navigation chip (when removed, redirects the user back to a specific url)
- add from any place n the app a chip
- ...

So I got the basics working, hooking in the componentsRegistry, and being able to call it from any place.

But now I'm trying to get the chips from the chipFilterController into the `<md-chips>`

html:

```
<chip-filter md-component-id="testId">
  <md-chips ng-model="chips">
    <md-chip-template>
      <strong>{{$chip}}</strong>
      <em>(type)</em>
    </md-chip-template>
  </md-chips>
</chip-filter>
```

and directive:

```
function chipFilterDirective($log) {
  function postLink(scope, element, attr, sidenavCtrl) {
    element.on("$destroy", function() {
      sidenavCtrl.destroy();
    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    controller: "chipFilterController",
    compile: function(element) {
      return postLink;
    }
  };
}
```

and controller:

```
function chipFilterController($scope, $element, $attrs, $mdComponentRegistry, $q, $log) {
  var self = this;
  $scope.chips = [];
      function addChip(input, type) {
    var def = $q.defer();

    $scope.chips.push({
      name: input,
      type: type
    });

    def.resolve();
    return def.promise;
  }

  self.addNavigationChip = function() {
    return addChip("stuff");
  };
  self.addChip = function() {
    return addChip("stuff");
  };

  self.destroy = $mdComponentRegistry.register(self, $attrs.mdComponentId);
}
```

full codepen:
http://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/eJryqK?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

setting the `scope` to false (or removing it from the object) made it work